# How to store words from file line with separators into a struct

Tags: c, file, io

I have an input file named `cstats.txt` that only has one line:

```
name:age:phone:city
```

And I have a struct Citizen:

```
typedef struct {             
    char name[100];          
    int age;               
    char city[100]
    char phone[10];   
} Citizen;
```

I need to read from the file and save the attributes in the struct:

I tried:

```
Citizen a;
fread(a, sizeof(Citizen), 1, "cstats.txt");
```

But I think it isn't saving the attributes.

I searched here on SO but all I found was to read line by line.

Thank you!

Comment: Read line-by-line, then parse the line(s). [or: read one character at a time, then combine them]

Comment: The last parameter of fread should be a pointer to file.

Comment: mprove, A common over looked consideration is what to do if the input is not well formed.  How would you like to report that error?  Also, can any of the 4 fields be empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fread` is not the best(simplest) tool for this job, use `fgets` instead.

Read the whole line, after that parse the fields with something like `sscanf`, example:

```
char line[250];

Citizen a;

FILE *file = fopen("cstats.txt", "r");

if (file != NULL)
{
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, file))
    {
        sscanf(line, "%99[^:]:%d:%9[^:]:%99[^\n]", a.name, &a.age, a.phone, a.city);
    }
}
```

---

About `fread`, a good use case for it is to read data from a file that was writen to by `fwrite`, that would guarantee that the data would be appropriately formated to be read directly to a buffer like the one used to write, for instance:

```
Citizen a;
Citizen b;

FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); // open to read and write

fwrite(&a, sizeof a, 1, file); // write Citizen a to file
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);      // reset file position indicator
// rewind(file);               // alternative
fread(&b, sizeof b, 1, file);  // read data directly to Citizen b
```

In the above code I skipped return value checking for simplicity purposes, you should do it in your code.

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6odjBcSk4uMdZlHG)

Comment: Consider  checking `scanf()` result - good improvement with width limits.

Comment: can we use sizeof(Cititzen) instead of sizeof(line)? Sorry, it wouldn't have space for ":"

Comment: @improve, you are reading the data into `line`, the second argument of `fgets` should be the size of the destination buffer

Comment: @improve no! 2nd argument to fgets is how many bytes to read maximum. That needs to be the size of the buffer, not the size of something else :) - see https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yes, phone only has 10 chars, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MortenJensen Minor: "2nd argument to fgets is how many bytes to read maximum" -> Close but off by 1.  No more than 2nd argument - 1 characters are read.  Yet yes, it should be the size of the buffer to accommodate the appended null character.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica very good point and thanks for correcting me :D

Comment: @improve if you want to read direclty to the struct, the data in the file must be well formatted for that, I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, i can fwrite with a process 1 and fread with a server and they will communicate with each other right? Obviously, having the citizen a in process 1 and citizen b in the server but they will have the same data